# How to enable Gitlab as a login-Service in a Blazor-Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, gitlab, blazor, blazor-server-side

So in my usecase I'm making an Blazor-Server-application that has a high cohesion with a git-Service. As that git-Service we are selfhosting a gitlab instance. Because of that it would be nice to just log in with your gitlab Account into our Web-Application.

So to my question. Is this actually possible? Documentation on how to use external authentication providers in ASP.NET is scarce and the gitlab documentation is also not really the best.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should work the same as any other generic OAuth2 provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure [GitLab as an OAuth IDP](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/oauth_provider.html).

Here's also a [complete example](https://auth0.com/blog/what-is-blazor-tutorial-on-building-webapp-with-authentication/) of building in OAuth2 with Blazor. The example uses Auth0, but you can substitute pretty much any OAuth IDP, including GitLab because they all use the same protocol.

You can also see other examples using .net [openid connect](https://github.com/onelogin/openid-connect-dotnet-core-sample).

Comment: Thanks the toutorial was great. Sadly the Microsoft documentation is a mess